# SQL Azure/EF Code First - Login failed for user 'myUserName'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I'm using EF code first w/ SQL Azure database. I tried to do database migrations in Nuget PM Console using following command:(xxxxxxx is the SQL Azure server instance name)

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDb;User ID=myUserName@xxxxxxxx;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient
```

Then I got the error message:

> "Login failed for user 'myUserName'. This session has been assigned a
>   tracing ID of 'ab6fa467-e98a-4ce0-85b5-21638d9433ee'.  Provide this
>   tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance."

I'm pretty sure the connectionstring is correct since I copied it from the Azure portal. Also, I tried the exact same credential myUserName/mypassword to log on SQL Azure via SSMS and VS Server Explorer and they both worked perfect. My IP address is in the SQL Azure server whitelist.

I've been trapped with this for a few hours...Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, try:

```
update-database -ConnectionString 'Data Source=yourSource;User Id="username@servername";Password=yourPassword'
```

Comment: What goes in place of 'yourSource' ? The app name? Thanks.

Comment: The server name